# SSIS Import/Export Wizard ODBC/Snowflake timeout

Tags: ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timeout, odbc

We are using SQL Server 2014 (running the 12.6444 latest Service Pack/CU), and trying to import data using the SSIS import/export wizard from Snowflake, using an ODBC connection, using the latest ODBC drivers from snowflake.

It generally successfuly connects and imports data on small(er) queries. We're running a query that takes a few minutes to run, but keeps timing out  after 30 seconds, followed by this error:

```
- Pre-execute (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0047062: Data Flow Task 1: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (15) 
  Query has timed out. User specified timeout in seconds=30, Elapsed=45
```

We've already established timeout properties in the data source windows, but this didn't change anything:

```
Dsn=snowflake;query_timeout=0;commandtimeout=0;login_timeout=0;statement_timeout_in_seconds=4000;timeout=0
```

[image]

Anything else we should consider?

Comment: If you look in Snowflake query history what does it show? Did the query get cancelled and, if so, why?

Comment: It's not a snowflake issue. I can query the data directly in Snowflake Web/Excel without issue. SSIS is somehow overriding this timeout.

Comment: I know - and if you look at the query history in Snowflake for the query that SSIS is running you should be able to confirm why it is being cancelled and/or what settings SSIS is altering

Comment: The 30sec timeout is default for `commandtimeout`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.commandtimeout

Comment: You may be affected by this one: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb2954861-fix-query-timeout-expired-when-you-preview-a-command-of-an-ssis-package-in-ssdt-6ca8bc16-265d-7666-009f-91fdf1bc65fb

Comment: @Sergiu - That could be, however I've already applied  the latest patch/CU. This also behaves the same on my 2022 SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved.

I ended up saving the DTSX package generated by the import/export wizard, and opening it up Visual Studio – And after navigating through a bunch of settings, there is a `CommandTimeout` option which I manually set to “0”.
(This option isn’t configurable during the SQL import/export wizard).

This worked and the data imported successfully.

[image]